# Как сделать Андроид-игру сетевой?

Tags: android, сеть, разработка-игр, мобильные-приложения

Всем привет! Делаю свою карточную игру для Андроид. На данный момент готова версия для одиночной игры - то есть уже можно играть против телефона. Теперь хочу сделать сетевую версию - чтобы можно было играть против другого человека. Но пока не знаю, с какой стороны подступиться. Помогите с направлением поисков!
Принципы должны быть такими:

1. Игрок может создать свою игровую комнату и ждать, пока кто-то в нее зайдет
2. Игрок может подключиться к уже созданной игровой комнате
3. Игрок может выбрать "случайную игру" и игровая комната создается автоматически, куда перемещается он и его соперник, выбравший такой же тип игры.

При помощи каких методов подобные вещи осуществляются? Понятно, что тут в двух словах не объяснишь, поэтому и прошу просто указать направление для дальнейших поисков. И хотелось бы узнать, как с точки зрения алгоритма все происходит - обмен данными я имею в виду.

Answer (score 1):

нужен сервер с апи, на чем написан не существенно, смотреть в сторону веб сервисов, я бы подобное делал с помощью soap но я не специалист в вебе, наверняка есть более простое решение

Answer (score 1):

1. Если нужен именно веб, то свой
       сервер необходим. Там пишем
       веб-сервис свой, не особо важно на
       каком языке.  Реализовывать или на
       сокетах (на обычных хостингах не
       получится, так как там php и время
       выполнения скрипта ограничено 60
       секундами), или в виде обычных http
       запросов (передавать всё, к примеру,в json).
2. Если не обязателен веб (играть по
       блютусу или вафле), то один из
       телефонов будет в роли сервака
       выступать, а остальные как клиенты.

Comment: Не, это точно не блютус и не вай-фай будет. Обычная веб-игра. Про сокеты уже слышал, но пока не разобрался, как их пользовать ))

Answer (score 1):

Начните с сценария игры. Ну то есть как люди будут играть друг с другом, например:

1. Два друга играют через смски или там bluetooth
2. 10 друзей играют через некий игровой сервер
3. Мульон человек играют через Facebook/VK

В общем вариантов масса. Как только сценарий уложится в голове станет понятен протокол обмена, как только будет ясен протокол обмена к этому можно подтянуть и сервер/не сервер, p2p или что-то там еще.

Из того что вы написали рисуется REST-alike веб сервис с обменом json данными.

Comment: Скорее всего, будет свой сервер. Не уверен, что стоит подвязывать социальные сети. Буду искать про REST-alike. Спасибо!